# How to convert html5 web app in Iphone5 app?

Tags: html, xcode5

Trying to convert HTML5 webapp into iphone5 app using Xcode but getting failed every time. Want to know the code to convert HTML5 web app that convert it into iphone app

Comment: Your question is very broad. What exactly are you experiencing problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to directly 'convert' your HTML app to an iPhone app by adding some `meta` tags. This makes it possible to dock your app on the home screen. This doesn't make it a native app built with Xcode. For that, you need to be more specific in where your problem is.

Use this:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

Comment: Horman: i already have one html5 web app, so i need to write these lines into that project but how im going to open this in my iphone? need to use UIwebView??

Comment: @manishsingh: You will have to open this with Safari, and hit the 'Add to Homescreen' button.

Comment: ohh got it, adding to Homescreen will create an touch icon on the home screen of iphone from where im able to open the web app directly... ????

Comment: @manishsingh: you are right. You can configure this with splash screens, etc. Check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

Comment: @manishsingh: No problem. Since you are quite new, please mark questions that got appropriate answers as answered. See the [faq#accepted-answer]